# How to share on Facebook in Tridion based application

Tags: web8, api

We are using AddThis for sharing on Facebook and twitter, similar like below website :
https://www.tenaprofessionals.us/professionals/

You can see Twitter and Facebook icons in breadcrumbs , they are sharing using AddThis third party tool.

We now do not want to use AddThis in near future so we decided to integrate same sharing functionality in our Tridion based application.

So my question is do we have Tridion Api for sharing the things on FB and Twitter? Or has anybody implemented sharing functionality in their application can be helpful.

Comment: Consider recommending a ("share") Connector if you'd like on [SDL Community under Connectors for Web/Sites](https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-connector-ideas/i/connectors-for-sites). These ideation channels help show what's interesting to implementers and though only some ideas will be implemented, the feedback helps show interest in specific types of integrations and especially why for input into the backlog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no dedicated "sharing API" available, but you can more or less easily integrate your application with any other (services, applications, feeds, whatnot). The way how you do this depends on the type of your application, MVC based (DD4T, DXA), "old style" (Web Forms, JSPs), single page app, etc.

I have worked on an application which had sharing implemented via AddThis, so it's definitely possible, but it was a very long time ago and I don't remember the details. You should look at the AddThis documentation and apply all the necessary steps in your application, keeping in mind that the place (where and how) you apply the instructions varies on the type of your application.

**Update**

I misunderstood the question, my bad. But... the point still remains the same :). Read the Twitter and Facebook developer documentation and implement your logic as needed. There is no 'one size fits all' solution.

https://developers.facebook.com/

https://developer.twitter.com/content/developer-twitter/en.html

Comment: Thanks @atila for your comment, we are Replacing Addthis, current implementation is with Addthis only but due to some privacy issue buisness no more want Addthis, so we need to create same sharing functionality using Twitter or Facebook Api

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: +1. Also look at the [Facebook Share Button page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/#configurator) and related information if you need other functionality.